# Using indicator function to wrap up integrals over different intervals

Tags: integration, functions

Can I wrap up the following three integrals in one by using an indicator function? The funtion $f(t) = 1 /(b-a)$ is not zero only if $t \in [a, b]$.

\begin{align}
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq + \infty}} f(t) \, I_{[a, b]}(t) \, dt  =
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq + \infty}} \frac{1}{b - a} \, I_{[a, b]}(t) \, dt =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq a}} 0 \, dt = 0 \\
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq b}} f(t) \, dt = \displaystyle{\int \limits_{a}^{t \leq b}} \frac{1}{b - a} \, dt = \frac{t - a}{b - a} \\
\displaystyle{\int \limits_{- \infty}^{t \leq + \infty}} f(t) \, dt = \displaystyle{\int \limits_{a}^{b}} \frac{1}{b - a} \, dt = 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain what you're doing with words?

Comment: I think your superscript notation is meant to indicate that you always integrate up to $t$, but you are imposing different (and unspecified; e.g., $t \le +\infty$ really means $t > b$) conditions on $t$; I find it a bit confusing. Certainly you can "wrap up" several cases of a piecewise defined function into a single formula using indicator functions, e.g., $I_{[a, b]}(t)(t - a)/(b - a) + I_{(b, \infty)}(t)$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hello @CalvinLin I should evaluate the integral of the function $f(t)$ in the three pieces: first for $t$ in $(- \infty, a]$, second in $(- \infty , b]$, and third after $(- \infty, + \infty)$

Comment: That's not what the expression states. In it's current form, it says that a function is defined in 3 ways (but with no defining domain). The first way is the truth value of the statement "the integral of the 0 function is 0". $\quad$ Even with a generous re-intrepretation of what you wrote, it's still very confusing (EG See LSpice's comment). Hence, the request for you to explain what you're doing with words instead of just relying on mathematical notation condensing all of the work into 1 statement.

Comment: @CalvinLin I found here (°) the same calculation more or less, but I don't trust it, for this reason I asked here. (°) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzIctK5YE20&ab_channel=MatthewJones

Comment: @CalvinLin is the calculation in the video wrong?

Comment: @LSpice I explained in th comment my goal.